# What is the equivalent of ORDER BY FIELD in Codeigniter 4

Tags: php, codeigniter, query-builder, codeigniter-4, codeigniter-query-builder

I tried several methods but couldn't get the right result.

```
ORDER BY FIELD(c.id, '1,0,3,4')
```

What is the equivalent in query builder?

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Documentation says to do orderBy like this. ``$this->db->order_by('title', 'DESC');``

Comment: @Dula The question is really about how to use the `FIELD` function in codeigniter, not how to do basic ordering.

Answer (score 2):

You're free to run raw SQL queries in Codeigniter v4.

[Standard Query With Multiple Results (Object Version)](https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/database/examples.html#standard-query-with-multiple-results-object-version)

```php
$db = \Config\Database::connect();

$query   = $db->query('SELECT * FROM user WHERE id IN (3,2,1,4) ORDER BY FIELD(id,3,2,1,4)');
$results = $query->getResult();

foreach ($results as $row) {
    echo $row->first_name;
    echo $row->last_name;
    echo $row->email;
}

echo 'Total Results: ' . count($results);
```

Comment: Yes I know but I want to do this with QueryBuilder

Answer (score 1):

I believe this should work, for the query builder:

```
$builder->orderBy("FIELD(c.id,1,0,3,4)");
```